SAS proc tabulate many class variables
This question have probably a very easy answer.
I have 21 class variables , one for each year 2000 to 2021 and want to show percentage for each group (two levels)
  proc tabulate data=grundkom;
  class kommuntxt2000-kommuntxt2021 grupp/missing;
  table grupp='',(kommuntxt2000-kommuntxt2021)*N;
  run;

This works, but give a very wide table to read.
I want the 21 variables (years) to be under each other (they all have the same levels)
Landsbygdskommun Landsbygdskommun med besöksnäring Lågpendlingskommun nära större stad Mindre stad/tätort Pendlingskommun nära mindre tätort Pendlingskommun nära storstad Pendlingskommun nära större stad Storstäder Större stad
Example for first 2 years:

Tried only doing it straight forward in "proc tabulate", but maybe you need to transform data in some way.

So your posted example is what you want the table to look like? And you want percentages, not counts, correct? Also, it would be helpful if you can post a small sample of your data.

Counts or percent dowsn't matter.The variables are only grupp and those 21 variables on education.

Wouldn't it be easier if YEAR was a variable and not part of the NAME of the variables?  So instead of one observation with 22 variables you want 21 observations with 3 variables.  PROC TRANSPOSE should be able to do that for you.

Move the YEAR out of the metadata and into the data.
data grundkom_tall;
  set grundkom;
  array k [2000:2021] kommuntxt2000-kommuntxt2021 ;
  do year = 2000 to 2021;
    kommuntxt = k[year];
    output;
  end;
  drop kommuntxt2000-kommuntxt2021;
run;

proc tabulate data=grundkom_tall;
  class year kommuntxt grupp/missing;
  table grupp=''*year,kommuntxt*N;
run;

